# Redux isomorphic fetch in interval

Tags: javascript, interval, redux

I'm not really sure if the following solution is the best fit, and I would like to know best practices when manipulating state and/or Ajax isomorphic fetch requests, in this case, in intervals.

> **Users Module**

```
import { createAction, handleActions } from 'redux-actions'
import { api } from '../utils/api'

export const REPORT_POSITION_INTERVAL = 'REPORT_POSITION_INTERVAL'
export const CLEAR_POSITION_INTERVAL = 'CLEAR_POSITION_INTERVAL'
export const POSITION_UPDATED = 'POSITION_UPDATED'

export const positionUpdated = createAction(POSITION_UPDATED, (value) => value)
export const setReportPositionInterval = createAction(REPORT_POSITION_INTERVAL, (interval) => interval)
export const clearPositionInterval = createAction(CLEAR_POSITION_INTERVAL)

export const reportPosition = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
      return
    }

    function success (position) {
      var latitude = position.coords.latitude
      var longitude = position.coords.longitude

      if (getState().user.userId !== null && getState().user.currentCheckup !== null) {
        var data = {
          lat: latitude,
          lng: longitude,
          user_id: getState().user.userId,
          vehicle_id: getState().user.currentCheckup.vehicle_id
        }
        api(dispatch, getState, '/api/positions/add', 'POST', data, positionUpdated)
      }
    }

    function error () {
      alert('error')
    }

    if (getState().user.currentCheckup !== null) {
      var options = {enableHighAccuracy: true}
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options)
    }
  }
}

export const reportPositionPeriodically = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(setReportPositionInterval(setInterval(() => {
      dispatch(reportPosition())
    }, 10000)))
  }
}


export const actions = {
  reportPositionPeriodically,
  clearPositionInterval
}


export default handleActions({
  [REPORT_POSITION_INTERVAL]: (state, { payload }) => {
    return {
      ...state, reportPositionInterval: payload
    }
  },
  [CLEAR_POSITION_INTERVAL]: (state, { payload }) => {
    var clearedInterval = clearInterval(state.reportPositionInterval)
    return {
      ...state, reportPositionInterval: clearedInterval
    }
  },
  [POSITION_UPDATED]: (state, { payload }) => {
    return state
  }
}, {reportPositionInterval: null})
```

The `reportPositionPeriodically` action is called from the view.

The `reportPositionPeriodically()` passes along a `setInterval` arrow function to `setReportPositionInterval` which keeps the interval in the state and runs `reportPosition()`.

`reportPosition` calls a function named `api()` imported from utils.

> **Utils API**

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
import config from 'config'
export const api = (dispatch, getState, endpoint, method, data, success)
...
fetch(config.api_host + endpoint + query, params).then((response) => {
    dispatch(loaderActions.finished())
    return response.json()
}).then((value) => {
    if (value.message) {
        dispatch(loaderActions.fetchError(value.message))
    }
    if ((value.code !== undefined && value.code >= 200 && value.code <= 300) || (value.success !== undefined && value.success)) {
        dispatch(success(value))
    }
})
```

To clear the timer and stop the fetch requests, I perform a call to `clearPositionInterval()` which runs `clearInterval` on the interval in the state.

I find redux very hard and I'm having a hard time finding out how to do things properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is really nice, and your use of generated property keys is really good.

There's a few things you can improve upon:

> ```
> import { api } from '../utils/api'
> export const api = (dispatch, getState, endpoint, method, data, success)
> ```

If you're only exporting one item from the module, you should just export it as `default`:

```
import api from '../utils/api'
export default const api = (dispatch, getState, endpoint, method, data, success)
```

---

This is when you would use an enum type:

> ```
> export const REPORT_POSITION_INTERVAL = 'REPORT_POSITION_INTERVAL'
> export const CLEAR_POSITION_INTERVAL = 'CLEAR_POSITION_INTERVAL'
> export const POSITION_UPDATED = 'POSITION_UPDATED'
> ```

You could use the ES6 `Map` or [`enumify` on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enumify)

Answer (score 1):

It looks OK, but I would just return the promise from the api module, and handle the errors, success and so on in the place where redux lives.. namely in `reportPositionPeriodically`

This way your API-module will be smaller and more reusable, for instance:

> I find redux very hard and I'm having a hard time finding out how to do things properly.

you could replace it later, but the api methods would still work ;)
If you do so, you also have a better overview of your state and whats happening to your store